# Изменение параметров графика в Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Я занят 2D программой на *Python*, которая рисует траекторию движения тела y(x), пущенного с начальной **скоростью** под определённым **углом** к горизонту. Графиком я доволен, но только не могу изменить масштаб осей: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел, чтобы шаг на оси X соответствовал шагу на оси y (в данном примере 500) - это выглядело бы более реалистично со стороны физики.
Также мне очень важно, чтобы оси были подписаны.
Для отрисовки графика я использую *Matplotlib*.
Заранее спасибо :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *

U = float(input("U = "))
a = float(input("a = "))
PI = 3.14

a1 = (PI * float(a)) / 180
g = 9.8

L = U*U*sin(2*a1)/g

x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

y = x*sin(a1)/cos(a1)-x*x*9.8/2/U/U/cos(a1)/cos(a1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()

'''
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Create a figure containing a single axes.
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3])  # Plot some data on the axes.
'''
```

Comment: Начните с параметра `figsize=(35,5)` при вызове `subplots`. Хотя если у вас один график, то непонятно зачем вообще `subplots`, а не `plt.figure` у вас.

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно выход, но не для меня - мой график встраивается и должен быть прямоугольным

Comment: Попробуйте установить `scalex=False, scaley=False`.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл пока один выход - ограничить ось y длиной оси x - тогда масштаб будет соблюдаться автоматически

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *

#U = float(input("U = "))
#a = float(input("a = "))
U = 200
a = 30
PI = 3.14

a1 = (PI * float(a)) / 180
g = 9.8

L = U*U*sin(2*a1)/g

x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

y = x*sin(a1)/cos(a1)-x*x*9.8/2/U/U/cos(a1)/cos(a1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#Задание лимита для y
plt.ylim(0, L)

ax.plot(x, y)


plt.xlabel('Ось x', fontsize=10, color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Ось y', fontsize=10, color='blue')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А, ну так то да, `xlim` и `ylim` правильный выход в ваших условиях.

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения осей нужно вставить вызов следующих функций после ax.plot(x, y):

```
plt.xlabel('Ось x', fontsize=10, color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Ось y', fontsize=10, color='blue')
```

Подробнее об этом здесь: https://devpractice.ru/matplotlib-lesson-2-work-with-pyplot/#p121